# How to get the resource elements through context object

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, jndi

I tried to do establish a database connection through DatabaseSource JNDI look up.I followed the instruction in Tomcat website and did as below

I added the resource to  context.xml

```
<Resource name="jdbc/myDB" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
          url="jdbc:oracle:thin:111.111.111.111:1234:DBNME"
          username="Dobby" password="pwd" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1"/>
```

web.xml

```
 <resource-ref>
    <description>MY DataBase</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/myDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
```

In code

```
  Context initContext = new  InitialContext();
                DataSource ds = (DataSource)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/myDB");
                Connection con =  ds.getConnection();
```

If the connection fails I want to display the error message with the DB URL .How can I get the DB URL configured within the  context.xml ,in my code

Comment: Can you explain how the accepted answer solved your problem?  I have your exact question but I'm not seeing how the bean factory given in the answer is relevant.  Did you end up finding and parsing the actual xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed in the apache example, there is a one class called MyBeanFactory. From this class, you can get the resources from the context.xml file.

You need to check the connection is established or not in the servlet. If connection is not established, then get he value of the URL from context.xml using setter/getter methods and show the error message with URL.

I was doing same thing with IP address of server and got success. :D

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, you actualy use JNDI to get independent of these details, the only thing you have and witch you can put in your error message is the name of the ressource `"java:/comp/env/jdbc/myDB"`. The guy that did the administration/config will know witch DB-details this name is refering to.

Usually the developer of an app just defines the name of the ressource and passes it to the Appserver-admin. But when developing you have to/may play both roles.

**EDIT**

This is ofcourse  if you plan to use only the interface [DataSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?javax/sql/DataSource.html).

If you want to target a specific DBMS you may look at the implementation of that interface provided with the jdbc driver. Here is for example the Oralce implementation of DataSource: [OracleDataSource](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSource.html), more info about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/java.101/b10979/urls.htm).